# Application that requires admin rights

Tags: windows, active-directory, security, permissions, windows-10

We have AD and Windows 10, we have some applications that for unknown reasons requires admin rights. Is there any other option that giving local admin to user? Good practices? I cannot change software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application in question may not need full Admin Rights. This varies by application, but usually the need is only for write access to a normally write protected area where the application is storing settings. Programs Files, Program Files(x86), ProgramData%APPNAME%, or someplace in the registry hive.

In your testing you should grab [ProcMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) from the [System Internals Suite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/)

Once you have determined the locations that the application is accessing with administrative rights, retest without the rights and you will see the locations that are failing. When you compare the output of the two tests then you can create an security group in AD for that application and apply those rights to those locations by the group.

The problems with giving the Application admin rights instead of the user is that if there is a security fault with the application then those rights can apply to processes forked by the fault.

Best practices on the security group would be a note about who created it and a ticket number for lookup on the authorization of your security team where details about what locations need the access and at what level and for what reason. You want to document so that as new versions of the application are released you can evaluate if the settings are still required.

You can Change the software if you can demonstrate that a fault with the software which requires those permissions could compromise the security of the company. Then you go back to the developer of the application and get them to update their application or you will find another solution.

That ticket that you attach to the security group Description can have all of this information and document when a company risk official signs off on allowing more rights than you feel comfortable adding as a Systems Administrator.

Comment: By adding the locations affected by the changes to the ticket you also save a bunch of work for the next guy who has to make changes to the application without manually digging the information out of AD and the local machine rights. You may even be able to use the process as a template for other poorly written applications.